# Where am I making a mistake in the line integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the line integral

$$\int\limits_C (x^2+y^2)\, dx + 2xy \,dy$$

where  $C$ is the path of the semicircular arc of the circle $x^2+y^2=4$ starting at $(2,0)$ and ending at $(−2,0)$ going counterclockwise.

I tried solving the equation and got 0. Here is the link that shows a picture of my work. Can someone explain to me where I went wrong in this problem. Thank you!

http://i1317.photobucket.com/albums/t638/ayoshnav/Snapshot_20140330_zpsd18f1d9b.jpg
http://i1317.photobucket.com/albums/t638/ayoshnav/Snapshot_20140330_1_zps4b47d366.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your images, but here's what to do. Use $x = 2 \cos (t)$ and $y = 2 \sin (t)$ with $t \in [0, \pi]$, therefore

$$\begin{align}
\int\limits_{C} (x^2 +y^2) \, dx + 2xy \, dy & = \int_0^{\pi} 4 (-2 \sin (t)) \, dt + 8 \cos^2 (t) \sin (t) \, dt \\
 & = -8 \int_0^{\pi} \sin (t) \, dt + 16 \int_0^{\pi} \cos^2 (t) \sin(t) \, dt \\
 & = -16 + 16 \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{-48+32}{3} \\
 & = - \frac{16}{3}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Okay I had the same equation but why does the integral range from 0 to pi and not 0 to 3(pi)/4??

Comment: You are going from the positive $x$ axis to the negative. How many radians does that make? If you range from $0$ to $3 \pi/4$ you are still missing part of it.

Comment: Okay and what about the points...

Comment: I ask you: what about the points? Draw them: you have $(2,0)$ and $(-2,0)$. What angle does that make? Alternatively use $$\cos \theta = \frac{a \cdot b}{|a| |b|},$$ where $a = (2,0)$ and $b=(-2,0)$ if you're still not confident.

Comment: The answer is incorrect according the to back of my book. When I tried solving it I got -32/3 which is also wrong

Comment: Thank you, I had forgotten a factor of $1/2$. Does it match now?

Comment: No it still does not

Comment: I dont understand where you get 80/3... I'm still getting -32/3

Comment: Did you follow all my computations through? Also, what computations are you doing? I feel this would be best tackled through the chat right now.

Comment: http://i1317.photobucket.com/albums/t638/ayoshnav/Snapshot_20140330_3_zps7cf4350a.jpg

Comment: You are right about one thing: it is negative. I'll edit the answer. However, you are making the same mistake I did: notice that $$2xy \, dy = 2 (2 \cos(t)) (2 \sin(t) ) (2 \cos (t) \, dt) = 2^4 \cos^2 (t) \sin(t) \, dt = 16 \cos^2 (t) \sin(t) \, dt.$$ That's why you're getting $-32/3$ and not $-16/3$.

Comment: Thank you! It matches the book now too!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Sorry for mistaking computations twice.

Comment: No problem! It happens but seriously. Thank you for looking at my work and sticking with me until we got this right :)